# Restoring Contacts via developer console

Tags: contact, data, developer-console, undelete

I've deleted 260k contact records and want to undelete them via developer console. I tried this:

**undelete [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = true ALL ROWS];**

but when I click Execute I get the following message:

**Line: 1, Column: 1 System.LimitException: Too many query rows 50001**

any idea on how I could do this in batches instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to run the same script over and over again:

```
undelete [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = true LIMIT 10000 ALL ROWS];
```

This is what I do in the Developer Console, it's easy as pressing Ctrl+Alt+E for as many times as I need. Adjust the LIMIT if you're getting CPU errors, etc.

Comment: thank you so much! I will try this - I'm an admin and I don't know how to properly use the dev console.

Comment: will this also restore the records properly, including related records like activities etc?

Comment: I tried this with a small batch to just test it - and ran into the following error:               
  Line: 1, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Undelete failed. First exception on row 1 with id 0034H00001pXw3lQAC; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c duplicates value on record with id: 0034L00000MhYRH: []

Comment: @navreet That error means that you have records that already match a particular value, so it cannot be undeleted. Some additional work may be required to restore the data beyond just undeleting. And yes, undeleting a record will also undelete all related records that were deleted as a consequence of deleting the parent record.